# What happened to Dorian at the end of The Mask?

Tags: the-mask

At the end of The Mask Dorian gets flushed down a toilet that the Mask just conjured up by painting a flushing handle on a wall nearby. I never quite got what is supposed to have happened with him. Was he just flushed out of the building and thrown out somewhere? Did he drown? I don't think he was shown in the later scene where all his people were getting arrested. So what ended up happening to Dorian?

Comment: The same thing that happened to Captain Hook at the end of Hook when the stuffed crocodile fell on him…

Comment: I seem to remember him being collected after, but maybe that's a mental retcon.

Answer (score 2):

### **Dorian died (probably).**

In the [original script](https://sfy.ru/?script=mask), he's wearing the Mask at sunrise. It falls off of his face and he's killed (literally '*blown to smithereens*') by the TNT stick that he's been juggling.

> **DORIAN/MASK (CONT.)** *Do you hear? I'm immortal!*
>
> [The sun's rays hit the Mask. In an instant, he transforms back to
> regular Dorian. The mask pops off Dorian's face -- useless.
>
> Dorian stares dumbfounded at the TNT stick in his hand as it --
>
> **KA-BOOM! Dorian is blown to smithereens.**]

The novelisation (and movie) are rather more coy, setting up the possibility that he might have somehow survived. We're supposed to just accept that he got flushed away and isn't a problem any more.

> Kellaway might not be the smartest cop in world, but he knew better than to disagree with the man who hired the Chief of Police. He shook his head.
>
> "Okay. Whatever you say. Ipkiss is a hero and Tyrel is The Mask. Where is Mr. Tyrel anyway?"
>
> Stanley smiled. "I wouldn't worry about him. I think all his plans ... went down the drain"

Comment: So the original script had a darker ending for dorian and final movie decided to just leave it ambiguous. I guess that also explains why the mask does not work for Ipkiss when he wears it in Dr Neumann's office

Comment: @user13267 - Dorian also killed a bunch of extra people in the script. At the end of the day this is a family film, so you can't be too violent.

Comment: They should have gone with the style of the comics just to see what would happen

Answer (score 1):

*It's not clear, but we can discern some good ideas.*

It's appears (at least to me) that the Mask affects the world in real ways:

- When the bank was robbed, it really had a lot of money missing from its safe.
- When the crooked mechanics were punished, they really were impaled on muffler pipes -- but not killed.

So something unpleasant really happened to Dorian. But what? Another factor to consider is that the Mask appears to amplify the personality of the wearer. When Dorian wore it, murder and terror followed. But Stanley is a hopeless romantic with a massive streak of ironic humor. When he was confronted with force while wearing the Mask, at another time in the movie, [he danced with them](https://youtu.be/qfO_OfmGOl0?t=17) -- without hurting anybody. So some thoughts on Dorian's disposition:

- He did not die.
- He is no longer able to hurt anyone at the moment.
- As Stanley knows enough about Dorian's nature, I would posit that Dorian is no longer able to hurt anyone in the future.
- Stanley knows Dorian is a career criminal. So where would an ironically humorous hopeless romantic send a career criminal? My answer would be a chain gang of some sort.

My guess, which is only as good (or bad) as anyone else's, is that Dorian was flushed to a place where he is in chains. He is somewhere unpleasant like a Russian Gulag.

Alive and in a prison of sorts; And in a position to not hurt anyone now or in the future.